# merge 2 pdf page to 1 page

Tags: pdftex

I want to merge top half of 2 pdf pages (8.5inx11in) into one pdf page, one on the top and another one on the bottom!

I try below code but I still get 2 pdf pages:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[page=1,trim=0 5.5in 0 0,clip] {input.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=2,trim=0 5.5in 0 0,clip] {input.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I do not want to scale the pages but only combine two half into one final pdf (8.5inx11in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still receive two pages as output because your current insertion of the two half-pages is done within the page's text block, and that text block can't fit an 8.5in wide image. You'll have to place to two pieces in the page `F`ore`G`round using absolute positioning (use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` for placing content in the `B`ack`G`round). The following example does that using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  paper = letterpaper% Ensure this document paper matches included document paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}% Remove page headers/footers

\mbox{}% Set something on page so it can be shipped out
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    % Upper portion of page 1
    \raisebox{5.5in}{%
      \includegraphics[page = 1, trim = 0 5.5in 0 0, clip]{example-image-letter-numbered}%
    }%
  }
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    % Upper portion of page 2
    \includegraphics[page = 2, trim = 0 5.5in 0 0, clip]{example-image-letter-numbered}
  }
}

\end{document}
```